# RabbitMQ - Direct vs FanOut

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to understand RabbitMQ. It seems to be super confusing.

I have 1 exchange with direct type. It binds to 2 queues. I have no routing keys. If I publish a message, it goes to both queues.

How is this behavior different from Fanout? Or Direct is a subset of Fanout?

Answer (score 2):

Without any code here it is impossible to tell exactly what you are doing, so I have sifted through the documentation online and found some things that might be helpful. [This tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html#Bindings) on direct queues seems to suggest that a `fanout` queue is simply a `direct` queue where all binding keys are ignored.

> The meaning of a binding key depends on the exchange type. The fanout exchanges, which we used previously, simply ignored its value.

It then later states that the existence of a routing key will help match up with the binding keys if that is what you want to do.

> We will use a direct exchange instead. The routing algorithm behind a direct exchange is simple - a message goes to the queues whose binding key exactly matches the routing key of the message.

Then further on it stipulates that you can cause a `direct` queue to act like a `fanout` queue if you want.

> It is perfectly legal to bind multiple queues with the same binding key. In our example we could add a binding between X and Q1 with binding key black. In that case, the direct exchange will behave like fanout and will broadcast the message to all the matching queues. A message with routing key black will be delivered to both Q1 and Q2.

Perhaps this is what is going on in your case? Feel free to read through this tutorial to get a better handle on `direct` queues and the previous one (linked at the top of this tutorial) to see more on `fanout` queues.